# Breaking of query-string and retrieving value

Tags: apache, query-string, httpd.conf

I am using similar code as following in my httpd-apache 2.2 file

```
<Location /local/*/*/*>
setHandler dispatcher-handler
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*.*.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ www.dns.com/product.html?state=$1&city=$2&product=$3 [R]
</Location>
```

When I give URL-  `www.dns.com/local/1/2/3` in browser
In logs the query is breaking as following:

```
state=opt/apache/httpserver/htdocs/local/1&city=2&product=3
```

How can I code httpd file so that `state` must take only `1` instead of taking complete 'document-root' path and 'local' ?

Ideally I want `state=1`, `city=2`, `product=3`
how can I achieve this functionality ?

Comment: `RewriteRule` matches on the path component of the requested URI only. If you want to check the contents of the query string, you need to use a `RewriteCond` (see docs for details.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your target starting with "www.dns.com" which is missing the protocol part "http://" for being a standard-compilant URL. You can easily fix that by either changing it to

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ http://www.dns.com/product.html?state=$1&city=$2&product=$3 [R]
```

or by using a current-host relative path like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /product.html?state=$1&city=$2&product=$3 [R]
```

Comment: i tried with  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ http://www.dns.com/product.html?state=$1&city=$2&product=$3 [R]     and still getting same problem...........if i am giving   www.dns.com/local/1/2/3 ......state=opt/apache/httpserver/htdocs/local/1&city=2&product=3........i want to get rid of    "opt/apache/httpserver/htdocs/local'

Comment: i tried with  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ http://www.dns.com/product.html?state=$1&city=$2&product=$3 [R]     and still getting same problem...........if i am giving   www.dns.com/local/1/2/3 ......state=opt/apache/httpserver/htdocs/local/1&city=2&product=3........i want to get rid of    "opt/apache/httpserver/htdocs/local'

Comment: Read my answer again.

Comment: i am giving the rule in the way  you have mentioned. It is not showing up 'http://'  in my comment. I gave the DNS along with 'http://' -----------------------And same is happening with the second solution you have mentioned.--------- state=opt/apache/httpserver/htdocs/publish-9001/local/1&city=2&product=3

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry then. Are you sure you removed your previous rule?

Comment: How are you accessing the server? What do you type into the URL bar in the browser?

Comment: i am giving ...http://dns.com/local/1/2/3....and URL changes to http://dns.com/content/local/state/city/product.html?state=opt/apache/httpserver/htdocs/publish-9001/local/1&city=2&product=3